# Like button on website page link to like facebook page (differents urls)

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, facebook-like

I saw a lot of posts here and didn't find an answer. Let me explain. I have a site  and a facebook page facebook . com/example . com. In website there is a like button for each page, so users can like example . com/page, example . com/page2. So I don't know if it is possible that when a user like page1 that this like increases like on facebook .com/example . com> page?
So resuming :

```
facebook . com/example . com has 2 likes.
example . com/page1        has 1 like.
example . com/page1        has 7 likes.
```

I would see on facebook.com/example.com on middle left 10 likes.
Is this possible? If yes how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible, because every like button "likes" only one object. And there is no object hierarchy so that one object would consist of many other objects or one object accumulates the likes of other objects.

What you could do is to put a like button for your facebook.com/example.com page on every website. But in this case every like button shows the same like count. Then you can subscribe to the edge event with the javascript api and count the like-button-hits on every website: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

This allows you to display a counter for like-button-hits on every website but you are not allowed to display it as a facebook button.

Another solution would be to put different like buttons on every website and fetch the like counts with the facebook Graph API http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/. The sum could be displayed on the facebook page, but again not looking like an usual like count.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I hoped it would be possible, but this approche will complexify things and will give an headache.

Comment: yes, the answer is: It is not possible. And there are only complex solutions for a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have looked first in Facebook before you ask here (but I guess that's FB's fault as well because the link for its help section is at the bottom of the page and if you scroll down, the timeline keeps showing older posts instead of letting you see the bottom links). Check this: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

Comment: I checked this, but this is not what i was looking fot.In fact, if a user like page1 from my website, how can count of my facebook page increase when users like pages from my site? Thanns

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you are using a plugin in your website to accomplish this or using API directly. If you are using a Plugin, try Spider Facebook and it gives you a feature to add a hardcoded URL instead of a dynamic URL by page or by post. [Spiderrock Facebook](http://wordpress.org/plugins/spider-facebook)